# Flutter, image_cropper, how to resize at specific ratio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
   File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
                   .......
         androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(lockAspectRatio: false,)
```

This allows only resizing, but not keeping specific ratio (I want it to be 1:1).

I checked almost every parameter, but still can't find.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aspectRatio` property like shown below for keeping aspect ratio of 1:1 in image cropper

```
aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0),
```

Full code for image cropper

```
ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: originalImage.path,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0),
        maxWidth: 1500, //optional if you want to control the width (max)
        maxHeight: 1500, //optional if you want to control the height (max)
      )
```

Comment: Yup I did that too but after all you need to add lockAspectRatio:false if you want to resize it by hands. And it would destroys 1:1

Comment: What you need to do is set lockAspectRatio: true.

This sets the cropping rectangle so that it can't be moved or resized -- but the background can still be panned and zoomed.

The user can still choose a region of any size with a fixed aspect ratio -- but by manipulating the image, not the cropping rectangle.

On an actual mobile device, this is probably just as well. The chosen area will always be as large as possible, visually. But in an emulator, using the mouse, it can be a bit disconcerting at first.